# Solving circular references for a project that uses both C# and F#

Tags: c#, f#, circular-dependency

So here's my situation. I have a class library in C#. It exposes some types like `Rectangle`. It also exposes some methods for doing algorithmic computation.

It seemed like a good idea to write those algorithmic bits in F#. So I added another F# library project to the solution.

Now here's the issue. In order for the F# project to do algorithmic computations it needs to know about the `Rectangle` from the C# project. And in order for the C# project to be able to use the F# functions it needs to reference the F# project. So there's the circular reference.

One possible solution is to have a third project where I can define the `Rectangle`, then reference that project from both F# and C#, and then reference the F# project from C# so I can use the functions.

The issue with this is that then the user of my library would have to not only reference my C# project but also the extra third project (because the use needs to supply the input to the algorithm).

This isn't really acceptable since using F# is just an implementation detail and I don't want it to have any overhead on the way my library is used.

So let's say the `Rectangle` stays in the C# project. The "interface" to the F# implementation (the method in C# that calls the function in F#) of the algorithm is also in the C# project. How do I link it all up so it works? Are there any other options even?

It seems odd to me to refuse circular references. Tightly bound projects like this one don't really have a directed graph structure.

There's an extra method I'm aware of. The F# project having it's own `Rectangle` and then do serialization and deserialization on both ends. This is both tedious and contrary to the original idea of using F# to make my code simpler.

Comment: What about creating a rectangle interface in the F# project that the C# rectangle class implements?

Comment: Won't that still mean that references to the C# rectangle need a reference to the F# assembly?

Comment: Yes, but now the F# one doesn't need the C#. It just exposes functions that work with the interface.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't seem to work... I still need to reference the F# assembly everywhere I use the `Rectangle` class because it implements an interface from that assembly. Surely there must be a workaround for something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like your real issue is not the dependency itself, but rather concern over the 'packaging' (having to ship three assemblies and requiring linkage to more than one assembly by the end-user.)  In these scenarios, you might consider using [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ILMerge.aspx) to combine your assemblies into a single DLL.  This allows you to use proper decoupling in your projects while still having the convenience of shipping only a single file for your library.  This is a very commonly used strategy by vendors of third-party libraries.

There are also various commercial tools available that can perform this process and do other things like obfuscation, license enforcement, etc. but it's unclear whether that's really necessary for your application.

Comment: Yeah, I guess if the only concern is that the library user would also have to remember to reference FSharp.Core, it would be the easiest to write everything computation-related in F# library, then merge assemblies together...

Comment: @Patryk, ILMerge actually does support automatically 'internalizing' references, which means you can hide the public classes from the F# 'helper' assembly in the final packaged assembly, while still implementing them as 'public' for consumption in the original design.  In this way, you shouldn't actually require any reference to FSharp.Core.

Comment: This certainly is an option but I think what Matthew suggested in the comment might be the best choice. I'll see if I run into more complications.

Comment: I'll mark this as the correct answer since it answers my actual questions even though there are better ways to handle my situation that wouldn't result in this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your real problem here is not really a C#/F# one (although that triggers it), but that an assembly `A` can't re-export a type from another assembly `B` without requiring users of `A` to also take a reference to `B`.

I would suggest working around this problem by defining `Rectangle` in the F# assembly, but defining a new `Rectangle` in the C# assembly as a wrapper type, with an F# `Rectangle` as a private member. You can then expose the underlying F# algorithms with wrapper functions as well, and provide a constructor for calling code to use directly.