# Portable Class Library using F# without FSharp.Core.dll reference

Tags: c#, f#, portable-class-library

I tried to create portable class library using F#  which could be used for example from C# code.  But looks like using standard F# constructs, like `raise` makes *FSharp.Core.dll* necessary to use created Portable Class Library.

`raise(ArgumentNullException("parameter"))` is transformed into

```
Operators.Raise<Unit>(new ArgumentNullException("source"));
```

(where `Operators.Raise` lives in `Microsoft.FSharp.Core` namespace) instead of just

```
throw new Exception
```

I assume that's not the only F# construct which is compiled to some static method from *FSharp.Core.dll* library.

**Is there any way to create F# code (especially Portable Class Library) which after compilation does not require a reference to *FSharp.Core.dll* or any other *FSharp-specific* library?**

Comment: Where is the Problem with that reference?

Comment: You might want to look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21143464/1180426) to merge assemblies, although I'm not sure if that's gonna work with PCLs (?). Other than that, I don't think it's possible, even functions in F# do not use `Func<>` but `FSharpFunc<>` from `FSharp.Core`.

Answer (score 14):

If you compile the code with

```
--standalone
```

the compiler will do an equivalent of static linking.  As a result, the references won't be needed at run time.

This is probably the best you can do.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you would be referencing a portable version of FSharp.Core that have been built against a certain profile, rather than statically linking everything.

I think there are portable versions of profile 47, 88, and 158.

Comment: For F# 3.0 there is only profile 47, for F# 3.1 there is only profiles 47 and 7.

Comment: Only 47 is available open source anyway, I thought VS2013 packaged 158?

Comment: No, it ships only 7 and 47, unfortunately